# Uneven chest.... Please help

Tags: chest

[image]

Uneven chest. Please help..

Body fat will be around 9-11%

Comment: Curious how you arrived at 9-11% for your BF?

Comment: Agreed. That photo is 25% or greater easily.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't see it, and it could be the way you're standing, positioning your body, or holding your phone.

If you still see it and it bothers you, keep in mind a certain amount of asymmetry is entirely normal. It may be just be structure of your body.

If you decide you really want to do something about it, try exercises that recruit muscles from both sides of the body equally. For example, dumbell incline press or dumbell bench press. You'll be able to detect any imbalances there. Read more about this subject by searching for **unilateral** exercise.

You could also think about minimising any activities you do regularly which favour one side of the body. For example, always carrying or moving heavy objects in one hand.

Comment: That is one reason Zane was able to compete with Arnold, etc depsite being smaller, was freakish symmetry.